# Material Design Lite drawer breakpoint

Tags: material-design-lite

I need to set the Material Design Lite drawer menu so that the hamburger menu is displayed permenantly. The menu must be shown only on click.

There is no documentation available about this. Thank you!

[link](http://www.getmdl.io/templates/dashboard/index.html)

Comment: You should really provide some code for us to help you out.

Comment: Of course, here's the template page: [link](http://www.getmdl.io/templates/dashboard/index.html)

Comment: I mean, the code of your app. Not just the template.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to be honest with you and say I'm not sure what your asking, however.

If you are referring to the hamburger not displaying at all assure that your **mdl-layout** has the **mdl-js-layout**

Did you add the menu at runtime? If so, assure that the dom is updated after the fact

```
//yourCodeThatModifiedTheElement
componentHandler.upgradeDom();
```

Or is the navigation not showing up at all? Certain breakpoints will hide the navigation in which case you can have the header fixed which will display on all screen sizes by adding **mdl-layout--fixed-drawer** to your **mdl-layout**